Google sheet ROI formula not working
My Google sheet formula isn't working as intended.
In order to calculate the ROI of an event I'm making I use different stats and make a big calculation of points in the ROI column

The formula I'm currently using: =G9 + (H9 * 2) + (I9 * 2) + (J9 * -4) + (K9 / 15) + (L9 * 0.5)
But the ROI cases stay in Error and tell me there is an error in the formula and doesn't give any detail.
I've already checked every entrance and they are correct

Can someone help me solved this ?

what do you get when you click on "Erreur d'analyse de formule"? Can you upload an example set of data in this Blank Sheet Maker

Hi, I have solved this issue, it's actually pretty dumb, I'm gonna update the question tomorow

Unlike Excel, Google Sheets uses commas instead of periods for decimal points. As you can observe in the first screenshot, the last formula has a period and not a comma.
The correct formula should instead be:
=G9 + (H9 * 2) + (I9 * 2) + (J9 * -4) + (K9 / 15) + (L9 * 0,5)

That is why it wasn't working.

The decimal separator,borh in Excel and Google Sheets, depends on the spreadsheet locale.

As Rubén noted, if your spreadsheet is set to a local that uses the comma as a decimal separator, France for example, then 0.1 is a text string not a number.
That is why you were getting a syntax error.
If you had the locale set to the United States and used a comma as the decimal separator in a ccikation, you would get the same error.
This holds true for both Excel and Google Sheets.
